# How do you get a list of all domains for .com.au

Tags: web, ip, country-codes

I would like to know all website addresses that end in .com.au

Is it possible to get a list of them somehow?
Or perhaps a database of them?

If you can't get them all, is it possible to get an approximate list?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307553/possible-to-download-entire-whois-database-list-of-registered-domains

Comment: I have amended the question to be .com.au domains. The post referred to does not say where you can find those.

Comment: I had a quick look at http://www.auda.org.au and I couldn't immediately find whether they offer a zone file download service. Not all registries do.